# Component does not refresh values

Tags: reactjs, react-router

The "submitRecord" function adds to the array the values entered in the input
Then the props are transferred to the "EmployeePanel" component.
The value appears in :

```js
<PanelItem title="Zarobione pieniądze:" value={moneyEarned} />
```

But the value is changed not immediately but after entering the path again.
How to make a value appear in the field immediately after pressing the submit button?

```js
submitRecord = (id, e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let employeesList = this.state.employeesList;
    employeesList = employeesList.map(person => {
      if (person.id === id) {
        person.timeRecords.push(this.state.record);
        person.hoursWorked += this.state.record.hours * 1;
        console.log(person);
      }
      return person;
    });
    this.setState({ employeesList });
```

```js
<Route path="/employeePanel/:name" render={props => <EmployeePanel {...props} />} />
```

```js
const EmployeePanel = props => {
  const {
    id,
    firstName,
    lastName,
    email,
    phone,
    rate,
    accountNumber,
    timeRecords,
    moneyEarned,
    hoursWorked,
  } = props.location.state;
  console.log(props);
  return (
    <div className="employeePanel">
      <div className="employeePanel__data">
        <h1 className="page-title">Panel Pracownika</h1>
        <ul className="employeePanel__list">
          <PanelItem title="Imie:" value={firstName} />
          <PanelItem title="Nazwisko:" value={lastName} />
          <PanelItem title="Email:" value={email} />
          <PanelItem title="Telefon:" value={phone} />
          <PanelItem title="Stawka/h:" value={rate} currency="zł" />
          <PanelItem title="Numer konta bankowego:" value={accountNumber} />
          <PanelItem title="Zarobione pieniądze:" value={moneyEarned} />
          {/*TODO Przy dodawaniu Dnia nie wyświetla się natychmiastowo hoursWorked, dopiero po wejściu jeszcze raz w panel*/}
          <PanelItem title="Suma przerobionych godzin:" value={hoursWorked} />
        </ul>
        <ButtonRemoveEmployee id={id} />
        <div className="employeePanel__addDay">
          <AddDay id={id} timeRecords={timeRecords} />
        </div>
        <div className="employeePanel__timeRecords">
          <TimeRecords timeRecords={timeRecords} rate={rate} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: My guess would be it is because you are mutating existing state data instead of returning a new object, react can't reconcile the diff.  I think it works the second time accessing the route since your `submitRecord ` is actually returning a new array and the component is *then* accessing the updated person record.  Just a hunch and hard to tell since you haven't shared the code where the `submitRecord` callback is used, but maybe try spreading the matching `person` into a new person object and return that in the map.

Comment: Yes, try to rewrite your submitRecord in the next way

(`
    submitRecord = (id, e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let employeesList = this.state.employeesList;
    employeesList = employeesList.map(person => {
      if (person.id === id) {
        const timeRecords = timeRecords;
        timeRecords.push(this.state.record);
        const hoursWorked += this.state.record.hours * 1;
        
        person = {...person, hoursWorked, timeRecords);
        console.log(person);
      }
      return person;
    });
    this.setState({ employeesList });
`)

Answer (score 0):

When the function is called, everything is correct. But I noticed that when connecting to this.props.location.state there are no changes in the component

```js
const EmployeePanel = props => {
  const {
    id,
    firstName,
    lastName,
    email,
    phone,
    rate,
    accountNumber,
    timeRecords,
    moneyEarned,
    hoursWorked,
  } = props.location.state;
  console.log(props);
  return (
    <div className="employeePanel">
      <div className="employeePanel__data">
        <h1 className="page-title">Panel Pracownika</h1>
        <ul className="employeePanel__list">
          <PanelItem title="Imie:" value={firstName} />
          <PanelItem title="Nazwisko:" value={lastName} />
          <PanelItem title="Email:" value={email} />
          <PanelItem title="Telefon:" value={phone} />
          <PanelItem title="Stawka/h:" value={rate} currency="zł" />
          <PanelItem title="Numer konta bankowego:" value={accountNumber} />
          <PanelItem title="Zarobione pieniądze:" value={moneyEarned} />
          <PanelItem title="Suma przerobionych godzin:" value={hoursWorked} />
        </ul>
        <ButtonRemoveEmployee id={id} />
        <div className="employeePanel__addDay">
          <AddDay id={id} timeRecords={timeRecords} />
        </div>
        <div className="employeePanel__timeRecords">
          <TimeRecords timeRecords={timeRecords} rate={rate} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default EmployeePanel;
```

https://imge.to/i/IoBlW <- screen with console.log

Comment: This isn't really an answer.  If props or state do not change, then react tries to optimizes by not rerendering a component.  Can you include more of your code?  The `submitRecord` handler, where it is used (i.e. how state is updated), any of the routing code that puts data into the route state (i.e. how state is consumed), etc, etc... ?